# Recyclerview json data binding has failed

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I am trying to bind JSON data on to the recyclerView , but data seems not to bind to the RecyclerView. 
Surprisingly when i Toast the data i see it's available. What could be the problem?

```
 private void parseJson(String  result){

        try {
            if (result!=null) {
                String resultTostring = "" + result;
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resultTostring).getJSONObject("ScheduleResource");
                JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("Schedule");
                itemList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
                {
                    String DepartureAirport = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Flight").getJSONObject("Departure").getString("AirportCode");
                    String ArrivalAirport = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Flight").getJSONObject("Arrival").getString("AirportCode");
                    String Duration = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("TotalJourney").getString("Duration");
                    String DepartureTime = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Flight").getJSONObject("Departure").getJSONObject("ScheduledTimeLocal").getString("DateTime");
                    String ArrivalTime = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Flight").getJSONObject("Arrival").getJSONObject("ScheduledTimeLocal").getString("DateTime");
                    String Stops = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Flight").getJSONObject("Details").getJSONObject("Stops").getString("StopQuantity");

                    FlightModel model = new FlightModel();
                    model.setDepartureAirport(DepartureAirport);
                    model.setArrivalAirport(ArrivalAirport);
                    model.setDuration(Duration);
                    model.setDeparturTimee(DepartureTime);
                    model.setArrivalTime(ArrivalTime);
                    model.setStops(Stops);
                    model.Stops= Stops;


                    itemList.add(model);



                    Toast.makeText(FlightListActivity.this, "DEPT : " + DepartureAirport + " Arrival " + ArrivalAirport+
                            " Duration : " + Duration + " Dept time : "+ DepartureTime+" Arr Time "+ ArrivalTime
                            +" Stops "+ Stops, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview

                final FlightAdapter adapter = new FlightAdapter(FlightListActivity.this, itemList);
                flights_rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                flights_rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(FlightListActivity.this));
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(FlightListActivity.this,Config.POOR_NETWORK_CONNECTION, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        }
        catch (JSONException r){
            System.out.println("ERROR PROB : "+  r);
            //  Toast.makeText(ListOfFlights.this,"ERROR PROB : "+ r,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
```

In my Adapter i have attached the Layout which will have the appearance of the data in the List , and also my **POJO class** is set which has both ***getters and setters***, but when i try to attach the **`adapter`** on to the RecyclerView the data doesn't bind why ?

**EDIT**

**My Adapter Class**

```
public class FlightAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FlightHolder>  {


    private List<FlightModel> itemList= Collections.emptyList();
    private Context context;

    public FlightAdapter(Context context,List<FlightModel> itemList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public FlightHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.new_details, parent, false);
        FlightHolder rcv = new FlightHolder(layoutView, context);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FlightHolder holder, int position) {

        final FlightModel sr = itemList.get(position);
        final String DepartureAirport = sr.getDepartureAirport();
        final String ArrivalAirport = sr.getArrivalAirport();
        final String Duration = sr.getDuration();
        final String DepartureTime = sr.getDeparturTimee();
        final String ArrivalTime = sr.getArrivalTime();
        final String Stops = sr.getStops();
        final String DirectFlight = sr.getDirectFlights();

        holder.from_txt.setText(DepartureAirport);
        holder.to_txt.setText(ArrivalAirport);
        holder.duration_txt.setText(Duration);
        holder.depature_txt.setText(DepartureTime);
        holder.arrival_txt.setText(ArrivalTime);
        holder.stops_txt.setText(Stops);
        holder.dept_txt.setText(DepartureAirport);
        holder.arr_txt.setText(ArrivalAirport);


        holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              //  Intent i = new Intent(FlightAdapter.this.context, DetailsLocalLeader.class);
              //  context.startActivity(i);


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
;
        return itemList.size();
    }

}
```

**For more information , below is the link to the project :**
https://github.com/huxaiphaer/FlightsApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/adapter/FlightAdapter.java

Comment: please share adapter class code.

Comment: @tannitanna, check i have edited my post

Comment: Where are you calling your `parseJson` method?

Comment: @Barns, am calling it in a method called `fetchFlightsOnline()` , check this link https://github.com/huxaiphaer/FlightsApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ug/flights/huza/flightsapp/FlightListActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, get someone to review your code structure. Read and understand Java Standard Naming Conventions. Use a design pattern for your app, probably MVP. Use Gson library to parse JSON data for you.

To answer your question, I would say that your JSON structure is flawed. Your code outputs this error

> ERROR PROB : org.json.JSONException: Value "SOME_LONG_JSON" at Flight of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

It means that you are trying to parse a JSONArray as a JSONObject. In the `Schedule` array, there's 9th entry which is supposed to be a JSONObject(as seen in previous 8 entries). But, it is a JSONArray.

So, first 8 entries are like:

```
{
    "Departure": {},
    "Arrival": {},
    "MarketingCarrier": {},
    "Equipment": {},
    "Details": {}
}
```

and, the 9th entry is like :

```
[
    {
        "Departure": {},
        "Arrival": {},
        "MarketingCarrier": {},
        "Equipment": {},
        "Details": {}
    },
    {
        "Departure": {},
        "Arrival": {},
        "MarketingCarrier": {},
        "Equipment": {},
        "Details": {}
    }
]
```

That's why you get this parsing exception in try-catch block. So, you can do this to check if your object is JSONArray or JSONObject like this in `parseJson(String result)`:

```
Object departureObject = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Flight").get("Departure");
if (departureObject instanceof JSONObject) {

    String departureAirport = ((JSONObject) departureObject).getString("Airport");
}
else if (departureObject instanceof JSONArray) {

    JSONArray departures = (JSONArray) departureObject;

    // use for-loop here to get data from array
}
```

But, seriously, use POJO with Gson and simplify parsing process. Also, if you have control over how API works, try to keep an object of one type only. If it is supposed to be a list, it better be a list even if there are no items or if there's one or more.

Try these things, it might solve this problem, but I doubt it. You will face more problems with parsing I think. Ping me after you've done this.

<s>Also, if you try to parse all of JSON received by Server, you will see that it is not even complete. Look at the end of [your JSON data](https://www.hastebin.com/tomegeloco.pl).</s>

Comment: I could submit a PR too at github, but I think you should try doing it yourselves.

Comment: @Lutaaya - Rupinderjeet is correct. The issue is because of inconsistent data fromat. Please check if the object is JSONArray or JSONObject. I have fixed it and works OK. Share your email I  will send the working code. 
But try to use  POJO with Gson and simplify parsing process.

Comment: @rupinderjeet, JSON received by Server is complete, Log.x has limit and hence it will not log full data. Just set that to textview you will find the data is complete.

Comment: Man thanks for the great all of you , indeed you are great developers

Comment: @Lutaaya - I have dropped an email. Thanks.
- rupinderjeet - no problem,

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris you might consider deleting the comment with your email unless you want it out there freely

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for your adapter:

```
public class FlightAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FlightAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {

    private List<FlightModel> mItemList;
    private Context context;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //TODO: Add all your views and the types hear!
        Public TextView mTvName;

        public MyViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            //TODO: add here for each view in your row
            mTvName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        }
    }


    public FlightAdapter(Context context,List<FlightModel> itemList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mItemList = itemList;
    }


    @Override
    public FlightHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.new_details, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(layoutView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FlightHolder holder, int position) {
        FlightModel model = mItemList.get(position);

        //TODO: Add for each view and data point!!
        String name = model.getName();
        holder.mTvName.setText(name);

        holder.layoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              //  Intent i = new Intent(FlightAdapter.this.context, DetailsLocalLeader.class);
              //  context.startActivity(i);


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItemList.size();
    }

}
```

**Disclaimer!**

I typed this in a text editor, so there might be a few syntax errors or misspellings. Please let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hello @Barns , i don't why it has refused i tried all possibe means but it has refused

Comment: What is refused. Where is the error? Method? Class?

Comment: Maybe for more information the link is here https://github.com/huxaiphaer/FlightsApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java

Comment: Well, no error occurs , but the activity shows nothing , meaning the RecyclerView is not set to data , but i see everyting is right maybe please if you dont mind and you navigate through that link

Comment: and surprisingly in my code i placed a toast to see if the JSON data is available , the toast shows that the data is available

Comment: I made that already , check it out https://github.com/huxaiphaer/FlightsApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/adapter/FlightAdapter.java